# How to add pictures to memory game in java

Tags: java, swing, awt

How to add pictures to memory game? I made it like a number game and now want to add pictures so that players can play a picture flip memory game. I have attached the code, and Board.java is somewhere changes are needed. I am really stuck on this one, any help will be appreciated.

Code.java

```
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class Card extends JButton{
    private String id;
    private boolean matched = false;


    public void setId(String val){
        this.id = val;
    }

    public String getId(){
        return this.id;
    }


    public void setMatched(boolean matched){
        this.matched = matched;
    }

    public boolean getMatched(){
        return this.matched;
    }
}
```

Game.java

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Game{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Board b = new Board();
        b.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500)); //need to use this instead of setSize
        b.setLocation(500, 250);
        b.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        b.pack();
        b.setVisible(true);
    }   
}
```

Board.java

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Board extends JFrame{
    private List<Card> cards;
    private Card selectedCard;
    private Card c1;
    private Card c2;
    private Timer t;
    static String fruits[] = {"pear.jpg", "peach.jpg", "pineapple.jpg", "/apple.jpg",
    "avocado.jpg", "/greenapple.jpg"};
    static String files[] = fruits;

    public Board(){

        int pairs = 14;
        List<Card> cardsList = new ArrayList<Card>();
        List<String> cardVals = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < pairs; i++){
            cardVals.add(i, fruits[i]);
            cardVals.add(i, fruits[i]);
        }
        Collections.shuffle(cardVals);

        for (String val : cardVals){
            Card c = new Card();
            c.setId(val);
            c.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
                    selectedCard = c;
                    doTurn();
                }
            });
            cardsList.add(c);
        }
        this.cards = cardsList;
        //set up the timer
        t = new Timer(750, new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
                checkCards();
            }
        });

        t.setRepeats(false);

        //set up the board itself
        Container pane = getContentPane();
        pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 5));
        for (Card c : cards){
            pane.add(c);
        }
    }

    public void doTurn(){
        if (c1 == null && c2 == null){
            c1 = selectedCard;
            c1.setText(String.valueOf(c1.getId()));
        }

        if (c1 != null && c1 != selectedCard && c2 == null){
            c2 = selectedCard;
            c2.setText(String.valueOf(c2.getId()));
            t.start();

        }
    }

    public void checkCards(){
        if (c1.getId() == c2.getId()){//match condition
            c1.setEnabled(false); //disables the button
            c2.setEnabled(false);
            c1.setMatched(true); //flags the button as having been matched
            c2.setMatched(true);
            if (this.isGameWon()){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "You win!");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }

        else{
            c1.setText(""); //'hides' text
            c2.setText("");
        }
        c1 = null; //reset c1 and c2
        c2 = null;
    }

    public boolean isGameWon(){
        for(Card c: this.cards){
            if (c.getMatched() == false){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: I you have an image like a JPEG, you can load it with the `ImageIO.read()` method, and then display it with `JImageIcon( image )` and then `JLabel( imageIcon )`, then add the label to your GUI.

Comment: I believe my loop is the one that has problems, and so I'm not able to have it to work @markspace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First line in method `checkCards` is:

```java
if (c1.getId() == c2.getId()){//match condition
```

It should be:

```java
if (c1.getId().equals(c2.getId())){
```

Refer to [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

You don't need a class that extends [JButton](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html). A [Component](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Component.html) has a *name* so use methods `setName(String)` and `getName()` rather than adding an ID field. Also, a [JComponent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/jcomponent.html#properties) supports custom properties so make the `matched` flag a custom property.

The first `for` loop, in the constructor of class `Board`, throws `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` since you only have six images in array `fruits`. I assume that you want each image to appear on two different cards. The loop should be:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++){
    cardVals.add(fruits[i]);
    cardVals.add(fruits[i]);
}
```

Refer to the *javadoc* for methods `add(E)` and `add(int, E)`. Method `add(E)` simply adds to the end of the list.

So now you want the `JButton`s to show an icon rather than text. So first you need to create the icons. Initially, none of the `JButton`s has an icon. Then, when the user clicks on a `JButton` you want to add an appropriate icon to it. You also need to be able to remove the icon. You can do this via method `setIcon`. If the method parameter is null, the icon is removed and when the parameter is not null, an icon is added to the `JButton`.

I use a `Map` to associate a `JButton` with its icon. The `Map` key is the *ID* attribute in your `Card` class and the `Map` value is the actual icon.

To keep things simple, I added all the icon files to the same package as your `Board` class. Refer to [How to Use Icons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) for more details about creating icons in *Swing*.

```java
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Board extends JFrame {
    private static final String  MATCHED = "MATCHED";
    private static final Map<String, Icon>  ICONS;

    private List<JButton> cards;
    private JButton selectedCard;
    private JButton c1;
    private JButton c2;
    private Timer t;
    static String fruits[] = {"pear.png",
                              "peach.png",
                              "pineapple.png",
                              "apple.png",
                              "avocado.png",
                              "greenapple.png"};
    static String files[] = fruits;

    static {
        ICONS = new HashMap<>(fruits.length);
        Class<?> theClass = Board.class;
        for (int i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
            ICONS.put(fruits[i], new ImageIcon(theClass.getResource(fruits[i])));
        }
    }

    public Board() {
        List<JButton> cardsList = new ArrayList<JButton>();
        List<String> cardVals = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++){
            cardVals.add(fruits[i]);
            cardVals.add(fruits[i]);
        }
        Collections.shuffle(cardVals);
        for (String val : cardVals){
            JButton c = new JButton();
            c.setName(val);
            c.putClientProperty(MATCHED, Boolean.FALSE);
            c.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
                    selectedCard = c;
                    doTurn();
                }
            });
            cardsList.add(c);
        }
        this.cards = cardsList;
        //set up the timer
        t = new Timer(750, new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
                checkCards();
            }
        });
        t.setRepeats(false);
        //set up the board itself
        Container pane = getContentPane();
        pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 5));
        for (JButton c : cards){
            pane.add(c);
        }
    }

    public void doTurn(){
        if (c1 == null && c2 == null){
            c1 = selectedCard;
            c1.setIcon(ICONS.get(c1.getName()));
        }
        if (c1 != null && c1 != selectedCard && c2 == null){
            c2 = selectedCard;
            c2.setIcon(ICONS.get(c2.getName()));
            t.start();
        }
    }

    public void checkCards(){
        if (c1.getName().equals(c2.getName())) { //match condition
            c1.setEnabled(false); //disables the button
            c2.setEnabled(false);
            c1.putClientProperty(MATCHED, Boolean.TRUE); //flags the button as having been matched
            c2.putClientProperty(MATCHED, Boolean.TRUE);
            if (this.isGameWon()){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "You win!");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
        else{
            c1.setIcon(null); //'hides' text
            c2.setIcon(null);
        }
        c1 = null; //reset c1 and c2
        c2 = null;
    }

    public boolean isGameWon() {
        for (JButton c : cards) {
            if (c.getClientProperty(MATCHED) == Boolean.FALSE) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Board b = new Board();
        b.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500)); //need to use this instead of setSize
        b.setLocation(500, 250);
        b.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        b.pack();
        b.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Note that I downloaded my own icons from the Internet, hence the names don't exactly match your names. Also, I placed all the PNG files in the same directory as file `Board.class` (i.e. the file created when compiling the Java source code).

Comment: Thank you; I am getting this error ```Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toExternalForm()" because "location" is null
        at java.desktop/javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:217)
        at Board.<clinit>(Board.java:34)```

Comment: @Aytida post a new question. Post a [mcve]. Post the entire stack trace.

Comment: It worked actually, thank you so much. Can you help me figure out JUnit test case for this? @Abra

Comment: @Aytida _Can you help me figure out JUnit test case for this?_ Post a new question!